# Set select box value and text

Tags: jquery

I know this is very silly question but I am stuck .
I have select box

```
 <select class="valid sbi" name="FORM[rd]" id="rd" data-error="">
         <option value="1">11</option>
 </select>
```

and data (text and value)

```
...
     $.ajax({
                url: '123.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {post_data:post_data},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(data) {


                }
```

and I want to set value and text to each option in the select box

```
 <select class="valid sbi" name="FORM[rd]" id="rd" data-error="">
             <option value="1">11</option>
             <option value="2">22</option>
             <option value="3">33</option>
                ...
     </select>
```

Please give me some suggestion

Thanks and regards

Comment: You want to construct a dynamic select box from the data returned through AJAX right? How is your data values in the JSON? Which server side language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are getting the option related data via the post ajax call. So it would be like

```
$.ajax({
            url: '123.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {post_data:post_data},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {

                //if data send is like [{value:'k2',text:kk1},{value:'k1',text:kk2},{value:'k3',text:kk3}]

                var html = "";
                for(x in data) {
                      html += "<option '"+data[x].value+"'>"+data[x].text+"</option>"
                }
                $("#rd").html(html);//append the generated html into select box


            }
});
```

#### note:

your looping logic in success callback differs according to the ajax response.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '123.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {post_data:post_data},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
       for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
           var option = document.createElement("option");
           option.value = data[i].value;
           option.innerHTML = data[i].text;

           //or for example "select[name='FORM[rd]']" or simply "#rd"
           $(".valid.sbi").append(option);
       }
    }
});
```

...that would be the simplest way i know (the for loop is written without knowledge of the structure of the response, and has to be altered ofcourse)